# Let $S$ be $G$-set with $S,G$ finite. If $x \in G$, let $F_S(x) := \{s \in S | xs = s\}$. Show that # of orbits is $1/{|G|} \sum_{x \in G} |F_S(x)|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a $G$-set. Suppose that both $S$ and $G$ are finite. Given $x \in G$, let $F_S(x) := \{s \in S | xs = s\}.$
 Show that the number of orbits $N$ of this action satisfies 
$N = \frac{1}{|G|} \displaystyle\sum_{x \in G} |F_S(x)|$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $\Omega=\{(s,x)\in S\times G\mid x\cdot s = s\}$. There are two ways to count the number of elements of $\Omega$. Either for every element $s$ of $S$ you count the elements $g$ that fixes $s$ : $$|\Omega|=\sum_{s\in S} |G_s|$$ where $G_s=\{g\in G\mid g\cdot s = s\}$ is the centralizer of $s$. Or for every element $g\in G$ you count the number of elements in $S$ that is fixed by $g$ : $$|\Omega|=\sum_{g\in G} |F_S(g)|$$

Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem states that $|Orb(s)|\cdot |G_s| = |G|$ where $Orb(s)$ denotes the orbit of $s$.

Now the number of orbits is : $$\sum_{s\in S}\frac{1}{|Orb(s)|}=\sum_{s\in S}\frac{|G_s|}{|G|}=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in S}|G_s|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in G}|F_S(x)|$$ where the last equality follows by the argument above.